# extsort-doc-group.xxxx file grows rapidly and hang the mongo server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have a MongoDB 3.6 server with 5 replicas. Some times `extsort-doc-group.xxx` file grows rapidly and hangs the server. Does anyone know the root cause for this and the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extsort-doc-group.<counter>` files are created for `$group` stages in aggregation pipelines when the `allowDiskUse:true` option is passed.

There should be only 1 such file per `$group` stage, and its size should be directly related to the amount of data processed by the stage.

Comment: Any specific solutions to overcome this issue?

Comment: The only real choices are get bigger disks, or rework the aggregation queries to need less space.